# html overlay in a silverlight app

Tags: html, css, silverlight, overlay, z-index

Having already read a number of articles on this here is the code I've come up with.
Can someone please tell me why the `<table>` doesn't overlay on top of the SL app? I'm aware the table I posted doesn't have anything visible in it but in my code it does.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #TABLESTYLE
    {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">
    #SLSTYLE
    {
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:0px;
    }
    </style>

     </head>
     <body>

     <table id="TABLESTYLE" width="100%" border=0 bordercolor="#5b5b5b" cellspacing=0                                           cellpadding=0 z-index=1>
     <col width="10%">
     <col width="80%">
     <col width="10%">
     <tr>
    <div style="font-family:Arial; height:128px; width:100%; background:#5b5b5b;">
     </table>

      <form id="SLSTYLE" runat="server" style="height:100%" z-index=-1>
      <div>
      <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2,"  type="application/x-silverlight-   2" width="100%" height="100%">
    <param name="source" value="xxx.WebUI.xap"/>
    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="background" value="white" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
        <param name="windowlessmode" value="true" />        
     </form> 


     </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but the good param name is "windowless", not windowlessmode.

see  http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc838156(v=VS.95).aspx

Comment: [US msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156(v=VS.95).aspx). Also, per this http://forums.silverlight.net/t/16731.aspx also include `<param name="background" value="transparent" />`

Comment: In all my time working with computers, I can honestly say that I have never ceased to be amazed by my own stupidity. Of course it's something so simple I didn't even think to check if it was correct. Thank you.